# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-18954.pth'

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I've downloaded python 3.6.1 and I'm trying to use terminal to setup *beautifulsoup4* but it keeps trying to install on python 2.7. Any help?

*Jakes-iMac:beautifulsoup4-4.5.3 Jake$ cd /Users/Jake/Downloads/beautifulsoup4-4.5.3
Jakes-iMac:beautifulsoup4-4.5.3 Jake$ python setup.py install
running install*

Checking .pth file support in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

> ```
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-18954.pth'
> ```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again

Comment: Can you clarify 'using terminal setup'?  Are you using pip?  You should check if using pip that is is pip for the 3.xx python version.  Same if you're using easy_install, make sure the correct python version is being executed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running the "python" command in your terminal will by default run Python 2 on many systems, even after you have installed Python 3. Try using the "python3" command instead.

Comment: Boom. Worked perfectly once I replaced python with python3. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Also, for future reference, [please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: It's not recommended to install/run dev tools as root. It's much better to properly install these tools as the user.